# how to calculate the missclassification rate/ Accuracy rate for clustering?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I am working with cluster models. I tried to find an accuracy rate/misclassification rate manually. I found an example that confuses me.

The example can be accessed from [here](https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/cluster-analysis-in-r/). I think the author find the accuracy rate wrongly. I think it should sum the diagonal values of the matrix (the result of the `table` function), then divide it by the total number of observations. Am I correct? or do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For context, the cluster table in question is this one, for the Iris dataset:

$$\matrix{\textrm{setosa}&\textrm{versicolor}&\textrm{virginica}\\0&48&4\\0&2&46\\50&0&0}$$

The main source of confusion here is that the discovered clusters need not be in the same order as the true groups. Indeed, if we appropriately rearrange the clusters/rows, we can see that accuracy can be expressed as the new trace:

$$\matrix{\textrm{setosa}&\textrm{versicolor}&\textrm{virginica}\\50&0&0\\0&48&4\\0&2&46}$$

In this case, it is clear how to reorder the clusters to match the true groups.  In the more general case, it might not be so clear how to assign clusters to groups, but you can look at metrics such as the [Rand index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) instead.

Comment: Thanks. So, you mean that the accuracy rate here is 96%? as explained in the example. So, I need to reorder the matrix to match the one in the true model. Is that what you mean? is there a function in R to find it for me?

Comment: Also, do we need to order the matrix based on the highest value in each row?

Comment: You can do that here, yes. In general, how to reorder might not be so clear-cut; you might have a cluster within which there is a tie for highest group count, for example. This is why metrics like the Rand index, which are invariant to the cluster ordering, are preferred.

Comment: Thank you so much.